# MVC non-area route problems (alongside areas)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

### How should I configure the following *non area* routes?

**/foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}**
maps to controllers in namespace myapp.foo.

**/{controller}/{action}/{id}**
maps to controllers in namespace myapp.

I also have 2 areas, **bar** and **baz**, they are registered with registeraAllAreas.

### My current setup

This is my current setup. It gives the problem below when I use the url /Home/Index.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("myapp/elmah.axd/{*pathInfo}");

AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

routes.MapRoute(
    "foo", // Route name
    "foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new string[] { "myapp.Controllers.foo" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new string[] { "myapp.Controllers" }
);
```

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Menu'. This
>   can happen if the route that services this request
>   (**'foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}'**) does not specify namespaces to
>   search for a controller that matches the request.
>
> The request for 'Menu' has found the following matching controllers:
>   myapp.Controllers.MenuController
>   myapp.Areas.bar.Controllers.MenuController
>   myapp.Areas.baz.Controllers.MenuController

Clearly there's something I'm doing the wrong way.

### Update

I also get the wrong adress generated when I use:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveSomething", "Home", ...
```

It renders `<form target="/foo/Home/SaveSomething"`

**I'm guessing that one cannot reliably use {controller} in two routes in the same area.**

### Update 2

It seems to work much better when I put the /foo route registration at the bottom.
This raises the question, what is considered a/the default route? (As the default route is reccomended to be put at the very end.)

Comment: Am I correct that the request which is failing is `foo/menu`, and that there is no MenuController in the `foo` namespace?

Comment: @counsellorben That's almost correct. I'm hitting /Home/Index through the url box in the browser. The corresponding Index view is in a master page which contains the following code: `<% Html.RenderAction(
            "Index", 
            "Menu", 
            new {
               theController = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(),
               theAction = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
            }); 
    %>`. There is no menu controller in foo namespace. I don't understand why it matches that route.

Comment: Is the master page in the foo namespace?  Also, why do you have the tokens "theController" and "theAction"?  Where are they used?

Comment: @counsellorben A mvc masterpage has no namespace afaik, but it resides in /views/shared if that is what you mean. The tokens are arguments to the action. The question is updated btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two controllers that has the name `MenuController` so MVC doesn't know which one to use if you don't give it more information. In you areas you probably have a files named something like `<YourAreaName>AreaRegistration`. Open those files and update the `RegisterArea` method so you route the request to the right controller.

From your error message it seems like the route is getting mapped to foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}, which doesn't have a `MenuController`. My guess is that you have a action link on a page under foo something something. That will generate an incorrect link if you don't specify the area for the link.

Try this to use the default route with `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Some text", "action", "controller", new { area = "" }, null)
```

If you want the request to go to a specific area just write it down in the call.

**UPDATE:** The problem is that when you write something like `Ajax.BeginForm("SaveSomething", "Home",...)` it will match the first route. You can't solve this by putting the area in the `BeginForm` statement as I suggested before since the foo route is not an area. You have two options, 1: move the foo part to an area, 2: put the foo route after the default route. If you put the default route before the foo route you will get a hard time rendering urls as long as you have foo in the same area as the default route (the default area), since the route engine will always find the default one first. However, you will be able to catch request to the foo route. So my best suggestion is to put the foo route in an area.

Comment: But shouldn't it go to the default controller as I'm not requesting an area url?

Comment: what is the reoute you are trying to get to and what different version of `MenuController` do you have?

Comment: /Home/Index in the default route. I have a MenuController in the default route and in each area.

Comment: But what is the route you are try to go to when you are getting the problem? What is you url? Is the namespace correct? Are you registering the routes in the correct order? Updated my answer with more info.

Comment: I'm writing /Home/Index in the adress bar in the web browser. I have added the namespaces for the respective area route setups. I'm going to do some more adjustments to see if that has improved something.

Comment: Adjusted namespaces didn't change anything. The namespaces is registered exactly like I have written in the question.

Comment: I see that you put the foo route at the bottom, just as I suggested in the comment: "Are you registering the routes in the correct order?" A default route is just a route that you want to catch basically everything, usually you want this at the end. The route that is used will be the first one matching, so in this case you have a route matching in the foo route causing you the problem.